# How can I attach listeners to DOM object when creating an Electron window using the BrowserWindow.loadURL command

Tags: javascript, dom, electron

I have the following code that renders a third party website in a BrowserWindow using the `BrowserWindow.loadURL()` method. Once it is loaded, how can I `require()` or otherwise import into that render process code/a module that would add listeners to various DOM elements to allow me to manipulate the guest website and react to events in the guest site?

I know one can load a BrowserWindow using an `index.html` file that contains a `webview` tag to load the third party site in a separate process, then use the `preload` attribute and the messaging system to execute commands and communicate back and forth.

However, I my use case, there is only one site that I will be allowing users to access and it is trusted, so I would like a cleaner, more direct way of interacting with it using direct JS dom event listeners from a normal render process or from the main process.

My use case involves plugging our internal support application into a web-based messaging service to help support people look up info and auto populate canned responses, etc.

`main.js`:

```
function createWindow(url, width, height, title) {
    // const {BrowserView, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

```
var win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: width,
    height: height,
    title: title,
    webPreferences: {
        partition: 'persist:albert-support'
    }
});

win.on('show', () => {
    // Attach listeners here somehow?; better would be to point it to a render.js file
});

win.loadURL(url);

// Close app if any one window is closed
win.on('closed', () => {
    app.quit();
});

return win;
```

}
```

Comment: Yeah.... we probably have no idea what Library you're talking about.

Comment: Electron, sorry. Man I'm tired....

Comment: If you don't know anything about the Electron API, and you don't understand the docs, I recommend switching to a Library People know about, like jQuery... or just use raw HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: I understand them very well at this point but thanks.